# Img not showing on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have tried to get these images to show on mobile with no luck. They show in chrome and are on another page of the website and display on both desktop and mobile with no issue. But when it comes to these two sections the images don't show on mobile.

I have tried with the second section to place the image in the div and use it as a background image, the image dimensions show on mobile but the image doesn't. The first section only shows the alt text.

```css
.civils-product {
  background-color: #ccc;
border-radius: 2%;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
text-decoration: none;
}

.civils-product:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.civils-product-box {
  border-radius: 2% 2% 0 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 25px auto -2px auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.civils-product-box img {
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 125%;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 

.civils-product-box img:hover {
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  left: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 120%;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 

.civil-works-photo {
  background-image: url(/resources/img/temps/civil-1.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="civils-product">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <div class="civils-product-box">
          <img src="/resources/img/temps/fencing-1.jpg" alt="jkjkljhg" />
        </div>
        <div class="civils-product-title"><h5>Civil Works</h5></div>
        <p>
          See More
        </p>
      </a>
    </section>

<section class="civils-product">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <div class="civils-product-box civil-works-photo">
        </div>
        <div class="civils-product-title"><h5>Civil Works</h5></div>
        <p>
          See More
        </p>
      </a>
    </section>
```

Comment: what did you use to access the html file in your mobile ? did you serve the files from a sever ?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/zwd8bpqv/19/

Answer (score 1):

you should add to the background-image .civil-works-photo {
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;}

```css
.civils-product {
  background-color: #ccc;
border-radius: 2%;
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
text-decoration: none;
}

.civils-product:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.civils-product-box {
  border-radius: 2% 2% 0 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 25px auto -2px auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.civils-product-box img {
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 125%;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 

.civils-product-box img:hover {
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(70%);
  left: -40px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 120%;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 

.civil-works-photo {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="civils-product">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <div class="civils-product-box">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="jkjkljhg" />
        </div>
        <div class="civils-product-title"><h5>Civil Works</h5></div>
        <p>
          See More
        </p>
      </a>
    </section>

<section class="civils-product">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <div class="civils-product-box civil-works-photo">
        </div>
        <div class="civils-product-title"><h5>Civil Works</h5></div>
        <p>
          See More
        </p>
      </a>
    </section>
```

Comment: Just fixed its self, unsure of why it wasn't working.